# Short story where a man ends up in the future & commits suicide

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Short story where a man ends up in the future when humanity has evolved into something unrecognisable to him & with no way back commits suicide rather than be alone.

I think his 'time travel' is a result of time dilation during a long space journey, cryosleep of some sort is a possibility but I'm pretty sure the main cause was time dilation, but either way it's a one way trip & there's no way 'back' to his own time.

Humanity has changed so much they appear grotesque & monstrous to him.

He ends up as a zoo (or museum?) exhibit or curiosity.

There's no way back to his time & he's the last 'human' he'd recognize as such so he commits suicide (jumps from somewhere high as I remember) rather than live the rest of his life alone.

The story would have been from the 70's or very early 80's, perhaps older.

Comment: Is he *successful* in committing suicide, or do the future humans keeping him captive always prevent him from doing it?

Comment: I believe he was successful in the end, your query causes me to think (vague memory?) there may have been  previous attempts they stopped but that could just be my natural suggestibility at work :)

Comment: I remember reading a story short story in either an SF magazine or anthology, with a man out of time in the far future. In the story, the far-future people construct and tear down *massive* environments of entire past cities and regions as amusements. One month the hot place to be is some city of the 20th Century, the next month the big party is at the ziggurats of Mesopotamia, etc. However, the "primitive" eventually discovers that his memory is a lie -- he's a prop created for their amusement. Is this the same story? I don't recall a zoo/museum ending, though.

Comment: @JacobC. The story you described sounds like Robert Silverberg's novella "Sailing to Byzantium".

Comment: @JacobC. thanks for the suggestion but no I'm sure that's not the one, particularly if user14111 is right & you were thinking of Silverberg's 'Sailing to Byzantium'.